# Windows calculator: Where is the e^x (= Euler's number to the power of x) button?

Tags: windows-10, calculator

I search for the e^x button in the scientific calculator of Windows 10.

I try to calculate e^2, but not with the "x^y" button like --> "e" + "x^y" + "2".
Instead, I want to enter "2" first, and then press "e^x", as it is available in any scientific calculator.

[image]

I do not see the "arrow-up" or "inv" button that [How do you use the Exp fundtion on the windows calculator](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/how-do-you-use-the-exp-fundtion-on-the-windows/a26a5a48-f2c3-4b9a-ae07-ce051974e9e3) mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange that I have overseen this.

**upper left button "2nd" --> "e^x" is on the bottom left**

[image]